# Duplicate files to folder applescript

Tags: duplicates, applescript, directory

I have this

```
tell application "Finder"
    duplicate folder "HD:Users:tcok:doc:Templates:Video:" to projectFullPath
end tell
```

But I need only the files in Template:Video to be moved to projectFullPath. Right now its moving the Video folder along with it, not just the files and sub folders within Video

Answer (score 1):

```
tell application "Finder"
    duplicate files in folder "HD:Users:tcok:doc:Templates:Video:" to projectFullPath
end tell
```

Just add `files` after `duplicate` to copy files only, or use `items` to copy files *and* folders.